# Adding new column to materialized view without dropping it

Tags: database, oracle, materialized-views

I have EMPLOYEE table with columns (EMP_ID, NAME)

I have created materialized view on this table with following statement

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON EMPLOYEE;
```

And I created materialized view with the below statement

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EMPLOYEE BUILD IMMEDIATE REFRESH 
WITH PRIMARY KEY AS SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE@DB_LINK;
```

Now i added additional column to the EMPLOYEE table and would like the materialized view to have it as well.

What is the best way I do it ? I prefer not to drop the materialized view, since we have other objects depending on it.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The type of change monitored by the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG is on data, not on structure. To add a new column on MVIEW you need to drop and recreate.
See Oracle Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm#i2063793).